# SQL Server make a count with a condition on a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, conditional-statements

What I need is to be able to add a column on my view that enumerates the records that meet a specific condition, right now I'm using row_number() to display in the column NU_COLA the row index with the condition.

```
SELECT  
OT.NU_ORDEN_TRABAJO,
OT.FL_PRIORIDAD,
OT.DT_ADDROW,
OT.USERID,
OT.DT_UPDATEROW,
OE.CD_UBICACION_ACTUAL,
OE.CD_UBICACION_CONFIRMADA,
OE.CD_UBICACION_SUGERIDA,
OE.NU_ORDEN_ESTIBA,
OE.NU_PLATAFORMA,
P.CD_ETIQUETA,
DT.DS_DESCRIPCION AS DS_DESCRIPCION_ESTADO,
DT2.DS_DESCRIPCION AS DS_DESCRIPCION_TIPO,
case when DT.DS_DESCRIPCION = 'Pendiente' then
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DT_ADDROW ASC) else -1 end AS NU_COLA


FROM T_ORDEN_TRABAJO AS OT 
INNER JOIN
        T_ORDEN_ESTIBA AS OE ON 
        OT.NU_ORDEN_TRABAJO = OE.NU_ORDEN_TRABAJO 
        INNER JOIN
            T_PLATAFORMA AS P ON 
            P.NU_PLATAFORMA = OE.NU_PLATAFORMA
            INNER JOIN
            T_DOMINIO_DET AS DT ON
            OT.ND_ESTADO_ORDEN_TRABAJO = DT.NU_DOMINIO
            INNER JOIN
            T_DOMINIO_DET AS DT2 ON
            OT.ND_ORDEN_TRABAJO = DT2.NU_DOMINIO
```

That gives me something like this:

```
NU_COLA
-1
-1
-1
 4
-1
 6
```

And I need this:

```
NU_COLA
-1
-1
-1
 1
-1
 2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In order to help you, we need a lot more info than this.  We need create statements for the tables involved.  They need not include all fields, but should have all relevant fields.  Secondly we need test data, ideally in the form of INSERT statements, such that if we use the test data and your existing code, we get your results.  That will give us a much better chance to understand how to change it, to get what you want.  My suspicion is the ROW_NUMBER() is not what you need!

Comment: Provide the business logic behind and sample data so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to split the query into two separate queries and UNION them together, the top query handles the row_number for DT.DS_DESCRIPCION = 'Pendiente', the second is the case where DT.DS_DESCRIPCION does not equal 'Pendiente':

```
SELECT  
OT.NU_ORDEN_TRABAJO,
OT.FL_PRIORIDAD,
OT.DT_ADDROW,
OT.USERID,
OT.DT_UPDATEROW,
OE.CD_UBICACION_ACTUAL,
OE.CD_UBICACION_CONFIRMADA,
OE.CD_UBICACION_SUGERIDA,
OE.NU_ORDEN_ESTIBA,
OE.NU_PLATAFORMA,
P.CD_ETIQUETA,
DT.DS_DESCRIPCION AS DS_DESCRIPCION_ESTADO,
DT2.DS_DESCRIPCION AS DS_DESCRIPCION_TIPO,
case when DT.DS_DESCRIPCION = 'Pendiente' then
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DT_ADDROW ASC) AS NU_COLA
FROM T_ORDEN_TRABAJO AS OT 
INNER JOIN
        T_ORDEN_ESTIBA AS OE ON 
        OT.NU_ORDEN_TRABAJO = OE.NU_ORDEN_TRABAJO 
        INNER JOIN
            T_PLATAFORMA AS P ON 
            P.NU_PLATAFORMA = OE.NU_PLATAFORMA
            INNER JOIN
            T_DOMINIO_DET AS DT ON
            OT.ND_ESTADO_ORDEN_TRABAJO = DT.NU_DOMINIO
            INNER JOIN
            T_DOMINIO_DET AS DT2 ON
            OT.ND_ORDEN_TRABAJO = DT2.NU_DOMINIO
WHERE DT.DS_DESCRIPCION = 'Pendiente'
UNION
SELECT  
OT.NU_ORDEN_TRABAJO,
OT.FL_PRIORIDAD,
OT.DT_ADDROW,
OT.USERID,
OT.DT_UPDATEROW,
OE.CD_UBICACION_ACTUAL,
OE.CD_UBICACION_CONFIRMADA,
OE.CD_UBICACION_SUGERIDA,
OE.NU_ORDEN_ESTIBA,
OE.NU_PLATAFORMA,
P.CD_ETIQUETA,
DT.DS_DESCRIPCION AS DS_DESCRIPCION_ESTADO,
DT2.DS_DESCRIPCION AS DS_DESCRIPCION_TIPO,
case when DT.DS_DESCRIPCION = 'Pendiente' then
-1 AS NU_COLA 
FROM T_ORDEN_TRABAJO AS OT 
INNER JOIN
        T_ORDEN_ESTIBA AS OE ON 
        OT.NU_ORDEN_TRABAJO = OE.NU_ORDEN_TRABAJO 
        INNER JOIN
            T_PLATAFORMA AS P ON 
            P.NU_PLATAFORMA = OE.NU_PLATAFORMA
            INNER JOIN
            T_DOMINIO_DET AS DT ON
            OT.ND_ESTADO_ORDEN_TRABAJO = DT.NU_DOMINIO
            INNER JOIN
            T_DOMINIO_DET AS DT2 ON
            OT.ND_ORDEN_TRABAJO = DT2.NU_DOMINIO
WHERE DT.DS_DESCRIPCION <> 'Pendiente'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change your query as below:

```
CASE WHEN DT.DS_DESCRIPCION = 'Pendiente' then
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY case when DT.DS_DESCRIPCION = 'Pendiente' then DT_ADDROW  else 'ZZZzzz' end ASC) else -1 end AS NU_COLA
```